# ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral whose two diagonals are perpendicular.

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a cyclic quadrilateral whose two diagonals are perpendicular. If $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle, prove that:

$AB$<sup>$2$</sup> + $BC$<sup>$2$</sup> + $CD$<sup>$2$</sup> + $DA$<sup>$2$</sup> = $8R$<sup>$2$</sup>

If the centre of the circle is O, I tried drawing radii perpendicular to each of the sides. That way, we get 3 pairs of congruent right triangles.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: the diagonals become the diameters of the circle, and then use Ptolemy's theorem

Comment: If the centre of the circle is O, I tried drawing radii perpendicular to each of the sides. That way, we get 3 pairs of congruent right triangles.

Comment: My bad, I meant that the perpendicular bisectors of the diameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Lemma.** If $ABCD$ is a cyclic orthodiagonal quadrilateral centered at $M$, then $$\angle AMB+\angle CMD=\angle BMC+\angle DMA=180^\circ$$

Here you have a "proof without words"
[image]

Thus, we have that $DA$ and $BC$ form a right triangle with a diameter, and hence $DA^2+BC^2=4R^2$. We similarly obtain $AB^2+CD^2=4R^2$...

Comment: Very nice solution. May I ask what did you use to generate the image?

Comment: @jjagmath, I used Geogebra.

Comment: Very nice proof, congratulations (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution.

Use this construction
[image]

to prove that $AB = 2R\cos(CAD)$.

By the law of sines we have $CD = 2R\sin(CAD)$, so $AB^2 + CD^2 = 4R^2$.